# How to store every key that's generated in a variable?

Tags: python

How do I store every key that's generated here in a variable that I can access later?

```
    for _ in range(int(amount)):
            key = str(uuid.uuid4())
```

**amount** Is subject to change.
How do I make it so I can print all of the keys that it generated after the loop is done?

I tried doing:

```
for _ in range(int(amount)):
      key = str(uuid.uuid4())
keys=''.join(f'{key}\n')
```

but it didn't work, only 1 key was stored into the variable.

Comment: `keys = [str(uuid.uuid4()) for _ in range(int(amount))]`?

Answer (score 1):

You can also store them in a list

```
keys = []
for _ in range(int(amount)):
    keys.append(str(uuid.uuid4()))
```

You can read about python lists [here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists).

You can then loop over your keys:

```
for key in keys:
    print(key)
```

Comment: I get the following error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'append'

Comment: @chronic you need to change how you declare `keys`. As you can see in my example, I declare it as list: `keys = []`

Comment: @chronic I suggest you start reading about different types in python, what is a list, what is a string ec...

Comment: Oh, my bad, I messed something up. Your answer works thank you!